# How to Handle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting `-1` from my `response`. I get this exception, how to handle this exception so that i can avoid any integer which does not match my `Array`.

```
Constants.Friends[Integer.parseInt(custom.getFriendsList())]
```

For instance if my Array Holds four items.

```
String[] MyList = {"One","Two","Three","Four"};
```

If my getting either -1 or any value greater than 3, **how can i handle them.**

Comment: You probably should check the index before trying to access the array.

Comment: depends on how do you want to handle them - either put a check of bounds or catch the exc

Comment: @isti_spl I've heard that it isn't good practice to catch an AIOBE...but otherwise good advice.

Comment: You aren't giving *nearly* enough context here. We've no idea what `custom.getFriendsList()` returns, or where the `MyList` array comes in. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: AIOOBE is an exception that you don't handle -- you fix the code that throws it. Simply check that the index you're dereferencing is in range.

Comment: ok good to know.. :) but then why so many answers, while a lot of down-votes of the question? was the question so trivial that insulted java developers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an *unchecked* exception, meaning that it generally signals programming errors, as opposed to conditions outside program's control. These exceptions should be *prevented*, rather than handled.

In this specific instance, you should check the value before passing it as an index to the array, like this:

```
int pos = Integer.parseInt(custom.getFriendsList());
if (pos < 0 || pos >= Constants.Friends.length) {
    // Handle the error and exit or re-read the pos
}
// Accessing Friends[pos] is safe now:
String friend = Constants.Friends[pos];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(custom.getFriendsList());
if (index < 0 || index > list.length)
{
    //notify user that input is invalid retry getting input
}
else
{
    return list[index];
}
```

This should do the trick; as I don't know what should happen when the index is invalid I left it open.

Comment: int index = Integer.parseInt(custom.getFriendsList());
if (index < 0 || index > list.length)
{
    throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException("You is in error");
}
else
{
    return list[index];
}